# How do i grab all users with their meta data?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am building out a website that has about 7500 users. What i wanted was to grab all of my users and their meta data and return it to me through a rest api call that I built myself. Currently I am having a hard time returning all of our users meta data and not just one single user's meta data.

I have already built out the custom endpoint and can successfully return users

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_register_route' );
function my_register_route() {
    register_rest_route( 'map/v1', 'test', array(
                    'methods' => 'GET',
                    'callback' => 'custom_phrase',
                )
            );
}
function custom_phrase() {
    $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
foreach($users as $user_id){
        return (get_user_meta ( $user_id->ID));
    }
}
```

I expect that the endpoint will return all of my users meta_data & user_data together instead of just the final user in the index.

UPDATE: I feel like I am almost there but each index in the array comes back with the exact same information. Not to mention i am somehow unsuccessful at grabbing the Active_Memberships values which is an array before it gets to me.

```
function custom_phrase($request_data) {
    $parameters = $request_data->get_params();
    $state = $parameters['state'];
    $users = get_users(array(
        'meta_key' => 'active state membership', 
        'meta_value' => $state, 
    ));
    $stack = array();

    foreach($users as $user_id) {
        $user_meta = get_user_meta ($user_id -> ID);
        $obj->display_name = $user_id -> display_name;
        $obj->memberships = $user_meta -> active_memberships;
        array_push($stack, $obj);
    }
    return $stack;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use return in your loop, so it will return at the first iteration.

Just create a variable to store meta :

```
function custom_phrase() {
    $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
    $data = [];
    foreach($users as $user_id){
        $data []= get_user_meta ( $user_id->ID);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I need to return bits of data from BOTH $users and $data and this does not combine them.